# media query non responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

OK so I have not used a media query for some time but i believe I have done it correctly.
I am not using sass or less just plain old css.

```
.btn-test {
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #2e70a4;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #2c83c9;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 18px 9px 0 0;
    padding: 5px 9px 0 9px;
    height: 37px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}


@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 850px)
and (max-device-width: 1050px)
{
    .btn-test {
        line-height: 34px;
        font-size: 8px;
    }

    .arrow-call-to-action {
        font-size: 8px;
    }

    .call-to-action-list p {
        font-size: 8px;
    }
}
```

so I set my screen to 900 where the media query should be active, however I see no change, have i done this correctly ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE HTML ADDED**

```
 <li>
                <div class="t4 arrow-call-to-action">
                    somthing
                </div>

                <div class="t5">
                    <p>text
                        <br>more text<br>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="t6">
                    <a href="#" class="btn-test"
                       id="some-tracking-id">Buy Now
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
```

Comment: show us the html part as well as an example what you are using any fiddle or html page complete

Comment: Np, I can add in the HTML

Comment: `device-width` with modifiers `min` and `max` are deprecated and should not be used more. Use `width` instead (`max-width` and `min-width`). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width

Comment: please refer this link for responsive media queries http://stackoverflow.com/a/35605310/5383669

Comment: Ahh perfect, lol as i said been a while. thanks you, plus one for the information and links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min-width` and `max-width` if you want to test by resizing the browser window. `Min-device-width` will not be affected by the resize because the device is not changing size.

Comment: Thanks, perfect, did not know of the deprecated update

Answer (score 1):

Try this

---

```
@media (min-width: 850px) and (max-width: 1050px){}
```

Comment: plus 1 but I am afraid grateful was first

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

<!-- Optional theme -->

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

<style>
.btn-test {
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #2e70a4;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #2c83c9;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 18px 9px 0 0;
    padding: 5px 9px 0 9px;
    height: 37px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}


@media only screen and (min-width:850px) and (max-width: 1050px)  {
     .btn-test {
        line-height: 34px;
        font-size: 8px;
         background: #fc9;
    }

    .arrow-call-to-action {
        font-size: 8px;
    }

    .call-to-action-list p {
        font-size: 8px;
    }
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <ul class="" role="tablist">
        <li>
                <div class="t4 arrow-call-to-action">
                    somthing
                </div>

                <div class="t5">
                    <p>text
                        <br>more text<br>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="t6">
                    <a href="#" class="btn-test"
                       id="some-tracking-id">Buy Now
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and the order of loading is also prefered